# Responsive Digital Signage (height)

Tags: android, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have made a weather page. So far I have it working on landscape but I want it to work on portrait mode. Right now I have it only working on a normal screen:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8my4m.png]

This is the script I made so far using bootstrap:

```php
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1"></div>
        <?php

            foreach ( $xml->forecast->time as $day ) {

                $dt = strtotime($day['day']);
                echo 
                '<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2" style="min-height: 80vh;float: left;">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                        <h3 style="font-size: 2.7vw; text-align: center;><a href="#">' . date("l", $dt) . '</a></h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                        <img src="images/' . $day->symbol['var'] . '.png"  alt="icon" style="max-width: 90%;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12" style="margin-top: 15px;">
                        <h1 style="font-size: 10vh; float: left;">' . floor($day->temperature['day']) . '&deg;</h1>
                        <br>
                        <h5 style="font-size: 5vh; float: right; margin-top: 10vh;"> ' . floor($day->temperature['min']) . '&deg;</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>';

            }

        ?>       
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1"></div>    
</div>
```

The problem is that it shows this on android xibo player in portrait mode:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5wxK.png]

I want it more like the landscape version, it only shows 1 day. I want it to show every single content without scrolling. The height is the biggest problem for this that I don't get it working.. Both images are a full HD webpage.

Comment: Permit me to say you : If you want 1/12 on smartphone, just have to use col-xs-xx ... You have class with just md or sm, so 'xs' is not defined, replace col-md-xx by col-xs-xx...     After, when you explode a 'col-xx-xx' you have to wrap the children in a 'div.row'    ex: col-xx-xx > div.row > (col-xx-xx + col-xx-xx)...

Comment: Well, the text is now overlapping so the only problem is to make the text responsive, and also it's still too high like the you see in the portrait version. also it isn't running on a mobile but on a tv screen. I am still missing the second temprature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oke after 2 days of working on it I finnely got it working!

I have used this script to make the text responsive:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            if (window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth) {
                $(".day").css("font-size", "2.5vw");
                $(".first_temp").css("font-size", "5vw");
                $(".second_temp").css("font-size", "5vw");

            }
            else {
                $(".day").css("font-size", "4vh");
                $(".first_temp").css("font-size", "6vh");
                $(".second_temp").css("font-size", "4vh");
            }
        });

    </script>
```

Also I changed the script to this:

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1"></div>
            <?php
            foreach ($xml->forecast->time as $day) {
                $dt = strtotime($day['day']);
                echo '<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" style="min-height: 80vh; text-align:center;">
                        <h3 class="day" style="color: white; width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;><a href="#">' . date("l", $dt) . '</a></h3>
                        <img class"image" src="images/' . $day->symbol['var'] . '.png"  alt="icon" style="width: 3vh; min-width: 90%;  width: 100%;margin: 0 auto;">
                        <h1 class="first_temp" style="font-size: 3vw;  width: 100%;margin: 0 auto;">' . floor($day->temperature['day']) . '&deg;</h1><br>
                        <h5 class="second_temp" style="font-size: 1.5vw;margin-top: 10vw;  width: 100%;margin: 0 auto;"> ' . floor($day->temperature['min']) . '&deg;</h5>
                      </div>';
                }
            ?>      
            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1"></div> 
        </div>
```